# Override some Woocommerce checkout fields with a filter hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I am using Wordpress 4.8.1 and using bridge theme .
I am facing some problem regarding overriding Woocommerce checkout fields placeholders.
Using a dedicated Woocommerce filter hook doesn't do any changes on my checkout page:

```
function override_checkout_fields($fields) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name'] = array(
        'label' => '',
        'placeholder' => _x('First Name*', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required' => true,
        'class' => array('checkout-billing-first-name')
    );
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name'] = array(
        'label' => '',
        'placeholder' => _x('last Name*', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required' => true,
        'class' => array('checkout-billing-last-name')
    );


    return $fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'override_checkout_fields');
```

I have used the filter `woocommerce_checkout_fields` too, but doesnt change placeholders, so I have tried using `woocommerce_billing_fields`, but there is no changes either.

Comment: I have tried `woocommerce_checkout_fields` and it works on the latest version of WooCommerce.

Comment: woocommerce_checkout_fields  and woocommerce_billing_fields both are not working for me

Comment: it's hard to give solution with this limited information. maybe try it on another installation of WordPress in your localhost to test if it's the same.

Comment: Is the theme overriding those fields as well? You could try giving your filter a lower priority (larger number as the priority parameter) in order to see if that's the issue.